# How to avoid reassignment of a variable on page load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm trying to come up with a function which will allow users to alterate data pressing buttons BACK and NEXT respectively.

I'm using this code for it:

```
         CounterID = IdArray.Length 'array of IDs

        determinator = CounterID 'determining which index is active and putting it on the top of array

        If Ident = 1 Then ' if button back is pressed
            determinator = determinator + 1
            If determinator <= CounterID Then
                'some actions
            End If


        Else
            determinator = determinator - 1
            If determinator >= 0 Then
                'some actions
            End If
        End If
```

It actually works. But partially. My problem is that whenever a button is presses the value of DETERMINATOR variable is again assigned to the maximum length.

Is there any way to avoid reassignment of this variable and make it happen only once?

Comment: Not sure to have understand your question, but [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)

Comment: The problem is that every time when I press ether button back or next the line `determinator = CounterID` assigns value of determinator to the length of the array. The question is how to avoid it?

Comment: for example if the array has 6 elements the determinator will be equal to 6. when I press button next it will deduct 1 from it `determinator = determinator - 1` but then the page reloads the value of determinator is again 6 because this `determinator = CounterID` happens again. So I can go back only one element of array only

Comment: Have you tried to assign the `determinator=CounterID` only `if Page.IsPostBack=False` ?

Comment: yes I tried it doesn't assing anything at all

Comment: its ether nothing or reassigns it every time

Comment: Just tried it again determinator is = 0 if I put it in `if Page.IsPostBack=False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use a session variable, something like this:

```
If Session("determinator") <> Nothing Then 
  determinator = Session("determinator")
else
  CounterID = IdArray.Length 'array of IDs
  determinator = CounterID
  Session("determinator") = determinator
end if
```

You may want this to be executed depending on IsPostBack.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working actually. And the solution is pretty simple. Tahnk you again.